# Send notification to approver if approver has not approved task in pre-defined time

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-foundation, alert

We have a requirement to send alert/notifications to approvers on pre-defined time if approver doesn't approve the task. We want this functionality for all approvers involved in each level of approval.

I have created workflow - it is multi-level approval workflow developed using SP designer. We are using SP Foundation 2010.

I would like to have assistance on how to achieve this task. Please provide details for this.

Answer (score 0):

There should be an overdue date/time in the SharePoint Designer. use the drop-down menu of the Approval action. This will automatically send them an email if it's overdue.

[image]

Comment: Hi Mike, Thanks for this. But I am using SP Foundation which doesn't have this option - start approval process.